# Selected property Compile error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm getting a compiler error for this block of code that im trying to run. Apparently the selected property is throwing a error: Argument not optional. Is there a better way to do this or a different property i could use?

```
 Private Sub cmbAnalyst_AfterUpdate()

    If cmbAnalyst.Selected = "" Or IsNull(cmbAnalyst.Selected) Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        whereAtt = whereAtt & " And Analyst = ' cmbAnalyst.Selected '"
        Call queryBuilder
    End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form_Load()
    whereAtt = "Select * from tblActionLog where LogID is not null"
    cmbAnalyst.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT Analyst FROM tblActionLog"
    Call queryBuilder
    End Sub

    Public Sub queryBuilder()
    testTable.RowSource = whereAtt
    End Sub
```

Comment: Gave it a shot. It's not using the selecteb property so it always steps into the Exit Sub instead of calling queryBuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ListIndex method of the ComboBox to test if something is being selected. You can also use Len() function.

```
Private Sub cmbAnalyst_AfterUpdate()
    If cmbAnalyst.ListIndex <> -1 Then
        whereAtt = whereAtt & " And Analyst = '" & Me.cmbAnalyst &"'"
        Call queryBuilder
    End If
End Sub
```

I would personally go for ListIndex. As ListIndex would return -1 if there is no selection.

Comment: That fixed it! thanks! But somehow my querry is bringing up no records.

Comment: You're Welcome ! :) What is your combo box bound column and are you applying the filter on the right column?

Comment: It's the whereAtt the select statement I put in it gets cleared when I reupdate cmbAnalyst.

So instead of Select * from tblActionLog where LogID is not null And Analyst = ' cmbAnalyst.Selected

It's just And Analyst = ' cmbAnalyst.Selected

Comment: Did you not use my Code? I have made changes, i.e dropped the .Selected, also you might need to requery your form to reflect the changes.

Comment: Yeah I changed it. The problem is whereAtt isn't properly updating. not sure how to make it global.

Answer (score 1):

From the Access help topic, *ComboBox.Selected Property* ...

*"The Selected property is a zero-based array that contains the selected state of each item in a combo box."*

So the argument Access demands is an index which identifies a member of that array.

If yours is a simple select combox box, you can check its `.Value`.

```vb
'If cmbAnalyst.Selected = "" Or IsNull(cmbAnalyst.Selected) Then
If Len(Trim(Me.cmbAnalyst.Value & vbNullString)) = 0 Then
```